# "Evaluating an integer at p" -- Gathen and Gerhard

Tags: abstract-algebra

I’m trying to understand the following sentences from Modern Computer Algebra, Gathen and Gerhard, 3rd edition, section 5.1:

> It is important to realize the similarity between evaluating a polynomial at a point $u$ and taking the remainder of an integer modulo a prime $p$.  The former is the same as taking the remainder modulo $x-u$, and so the latter can be thought of as “evaluating the integer at $p$.”

**Interpretation #1**
Irreducible polynomials are like prime integers.  As a matter of fact, both are the “irreducibles” of their respective Euclidean domains:  $F[x]$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ (where $F$ is a field).  So finding the remainder when dividing $f\in F[x]$ by an irreducible $x-u$ is like finding the remainder when dividing $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ by a prime.  But, by the remainder theorem, finding the remainder $f$ rem $x-u$ is like evaluating $f$ at $u$.Therefore, finding the remainder when dividing an integer by a prime is like evaluating $f$ at $u$.

This interpretation is comes naturally to me, but I find the language "evaluating the integer *at* p" (emphasis mine) confusing under this interpretation.  I would think "evaluating the integer modulo p" would be more logical.  We evaluate functions at inputs; we don't evaluate integers at inputs.  Can integers be interpreted as functions?  Perhaps.

**Interpretation #2**
An integer represented in a standard place-value numeral system can be thought of as a polynomial evaluated at the radix, where the digits of the integer are the coefficients of the corresponding terms of the polynomial.  For example:

$1101_2 = f(2)$ where $f \in \Bbb{Q}[x]$ and $f(x)=x^3+x^2+1$

$13_{10}= g(10)$ where $g \in \Bbb{Q}[x]$ and $g(x)=x+3$

If we think of an integer as being a polynomial whose coefficients are the digits, then the language "evaluating an integer at p" makes sense:  interpreting the sequence of digits as numbers requires evaluation of the corresponding polynomial at the radix. In that sense, evaluating a polynomial at a point $p$ (the radix) is like "evaluating the integer at p."

This interpretation is lacking because, of course, the radix needn't be prime; if Gathen and Gerhard meant something like interpretation 2, why is p prime and not just an arbitrary (nonunit) natural?  Furthermore, this doesn't have anything to do with taking a remainder modulo a prime p, which the first sentence of the quotation alludes to.

Is there some other interpretation of these two sentences that makes more sense?